# Data entry for DB DateTime field that may be null

Tags: delphi, datetime, datetimepicker

In Delphi 2010, I have a table which has a `DateTime` field.  This field MAY be empty.  What is the proper way to allow the user to enter a date and time value into a single field, where the field may be null or may have data?

Comment: JVCL has `TJvDBDateTimePicker`. Not sure, but I don't think it would have problems with nulls.

Comment: I looked at this.  it has a property called Kind, which tells the control to display/let the user choose EITHER date or time, but NOT both.  Thank you though...

Comment: Ok. I've only used it for displaying dates.

Comment: `TField.Clear` sets the field to NULL. As far as finding a control, that question is off-topic here. "Shopping list" questions (please post a list of links for me) are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Requests for recommendations are off-topic as well, because they're based on opinion. Good luck.

Comment: Then perhaps a re-phrasing of the question...  What is the proper way to allow the user to enter a date and time value into a single field, where the field may be null or may have data?

Comment: I cant test it right now. but what if you use 2 TJvDBDateTimePicker assigned to the same field. (one for date and the other for time)

Comment: Good idea. I tried that after reading your comment.  I added 2 TJvDBDateTimePickers, both pointing to the same column, one of Kind DATE, and the other of Kind TIME.  I set a date, then change the time on the 2nd one, and the date is reset to 1899, or whatever the '0' date is.  Looks like I will have to go with a non-DB component, and then programatically set things up...